# Excel : Sum Total of [h]:mm formatted column

Tags: excel, sum, formula, calculated-columns

I have an excel file, which shows date1,date2, and the difference between them, formatted in  [h]:mm

I cannot however sum the difference in these dates. It adds up as zero.
[image]
I kindly ask help, there is no answer that I could find anywhere

```
    T1                  T2                     Variance
2014/04/16 12:00    2014/04/15 14:00       =IF(B2-A2<0,"-"&TEXT(ABS(B2-A2),"[h]:mm"),TEXT(ABS(B2-A2),"[h]:mm"))
2014/05/16 12:00    2014/04/15 16:10       =IF(B3-A3<0,"-"&TEXT(ABS(B3-A3),"[h]:mm"),TEXT(ABS(B3-A3),"[h]:mm"))
2014/04/15 15:00    2014/04/15 16:00       =IF(B4-A4<0,"-"&TEXT(ABS(B4-A4),"[h]:mm"),TEXT(ABS(B4-A4),"[h]:mm"))
2014/04/15 15:00    2014/05/15 16:00       =IF(B5-A5<0,"-"&TEXT(ABS(B5-A5),"[h]:mm"),TEXT(ABS(B5-A5),"[h]:mm"))
```

Comment: The values in column **C** are **Text.**  The SUM() of these values will be zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First enter the following **UDF** in a standard module:

```
Public Function Addtime(rIn As Range) As String
    Dim c As String, m As String, r As Range, v As String
    Dim ttime As Long, zum As Long, b As Boolean
    c = ":"
    m = "-"
    zum = 0
    For Each r In rIn
        v = r.Text
        If InStr(v, c) > 0 And v <> "" Then
            ary = Split(Replace(v, m, ""), c)
            b = (Left(v, 1) = m)
            ttime = 60 * CLng(ary(0)) + CLng(ary(1))
            If b Then
                zum = zum - ttime
            Else
                zum = zum + ttime
            End If
        End If
    Next r

    abszum = Abs(zum)
    While abszum > 59
        hours = hours + 1
        abszum = abszum - 60
    Wend
    minutes = abszum
    Addtime = CStr(hours) & c & CStr(minutes)
    If zum < 0 Then
        Addtime = m & Addtime
    End If
End Function
```

Then in **C6** enter:

```
=Addtime(C2:C5)
```

this should display:  -40:50

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=myfunction(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

for specifics on UDFs

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**